# configSource doesn't work in system.serviceModel *or* its subsections

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf, configuration

I'm trying to split an app.config file into multiple files to make it easier to manage the differences needed for different environments.  With some sections it was easy...

```xml
<system.diagnostics>
    various stuff
</system.diagnostics>
```

became

```xml
<system.diagnostics configSource="ConfigFiles\system.diagnostics.dev" />
```

with the "various stuff" moved to the system.diagnostics.dev file.

But for the `system.serviceModel` section this doesn't seem to work.

Now I've read suggestions that it doesn't work for `system.serviceModel` itself, but it works for the sections underneath it: `bindings`, `client`, `diagnostics`, etc.  But the same thing happens to me when I try to use configSource with one of them.  When I put in

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings configSource="ConfigFiles\whateverFile.dev" />
```

I get:

**The 'configSource' attribute is not declared.**

Has anyone else seen this?  Do you know a solution?  (Perhaps I have an out-of-date schema or something?)

Comment: Works here - we use this every day in production. It's not shown and supported in the Visual Studio editor - but it works at runtime!

Comment: Question 1: have you tried naming your externalized file with *.config extension? 
Question 2: can you show us one of those external config files?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

VS.NET's editor moans about the config, but it works.

I have config like this...

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors configSource="config\system.servicemodel.behaviors.config" />
  <bindings configSource="config\system.servicemodel.bindings.config" />
  <client configSource="config\system.servicemodel.client.config" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

... which works fine.

Comment: Yep, you're right.  I see now that it complains when editing the config, but when you run the app, it actually works.

Comment: Ah, I see - it does work after all. Hate to say: I said so :-)

Comment: I've just been playing with this and discovered that configSource works on the `<client>` element but not an individual `<endpoint>` element.

Comment: extensions and services also works : 
    <behaviors configSource="WCFBehaviors.config">
    </behaviors>

    <extensions configSource="WCFExtensions.config">
    </extensions>


    <bindings configSource="WCFBindings.config">
    </bindings>

    <client configSource="WCFClient.config">
    </client>

    <services configSource="WCFServices.config">
    </services>

Comment: Late to the party and aware of it, but I had to set 'Copy to output directory' to 'Copy always' for each config file to get the accepted solution to work. Hope it helps.

Comment: Does anybody know how to suppress the warnings "The 'configsource' attribute is not allowed.

Answer (score 24):

It will **NOT** work on `<system.serviceModel>` since that's a configuration SectionGroup - not a configuration Section.

It **WILL** work just fine at runtime on anything below `<system.serviceModel>` - we do this all the time. Martin's answer shows it nicely - his sample will work.

Comment: If it WILL work on anything below <system.serviceModel>, then why DOESN'T IT work on anything below <system.serviceModel>?  I've read in a dozen places that it "will" work.  But it *doesn't*.  Hence the question.

Comment: So what you're really saying is, I'm going to get the error message whether I like it or not, but I should just ignore it and it'll automagically work?

Comment: No, I'm saying there's something odd happening here, since "it works on my machine" :-)  What version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 8):

One thing to be aware of when moving your config sections to separate files:  make sure your separated config file does NOT contain a configSource attribute.  For example, if you split your your bindings section out like so,

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings configSource="yourConfigFile.config" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

make sure that your actual bindings file doesn't contain the "configSource" attribute:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bindings>
    <!-- binding configuration stuff -->
</bindings>
```

I know that might seem obvious, but if you enter the configSource attribute, then cut and paste into a new file, it's easy to forget to take the attribute out.

Hope this helps.