# How to update an XBAP’s config file after deployment

Tags: wpf, config, xbap

Here is my scenario and would love any feedback.

We have a WPF XBAP application which gets hosted on our customer's IIS server on which we as a vendor do not have any control over. So as a part of configuration, clients first need to configure the WCF service to point to the proper endpoints. Default location for the service is say "http://localhost/XYZ.svc" which needs to change to proper adderess such as "http://USC.intl.edu/XYZ.svc" (offcourse our service is not called XYZ, just using that name as an example).

Problem in our test scenario is as soon as we change these values in the config file (Appname.exe.config) the manifest file becomes invalid and we start getting errors.

The solutions that I have looked at talk about mageui.exe. Our clinets may not have this utility. So how can we achieve this without using this utility and have the app be configurable.

Any input will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Salil

Answer (score 0):

Salil,

Not sure if this will help you, but when configuring WCF bindings, you're not limited to default Application config setings. An option could be to store the location setting in a custom config file and/or overwrite it programmatically, as needed...

Here are some interesting ideas that might help you and should work with XBAP as well; but I don't know if it actually does.

[WCF Configuration - Split it out of app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482835/wcf-configuration-split-it-out-of-app-config)

**Update**
You could try do use a second config file for WCF bindings as described **here (link see in comment)**. I got the Information from the topic above (thanks to *davogones*). Hope it works for XBAP as well.

Good luck!

Best regards,
Thomas

Comment: Here is the missing Link: http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2007/07/24/configsource-attribute-on-system-servicemodel-section.aspx