# How to get WCF configurations if you do ConifugrationManager.OpenExeConifguration()

Tags: .net, configuration, .net-assembly, wcf-configuration

This post is an offshoot of my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672564/net-assemblies-and-individual-configuration). However I have not tried implementing what was mentioned there yet. I've just learned the use of `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration()` to load configurations. Next question that should come naturally is how to manage WCF configurations?

What I have done: I've created a class library project (called `A`), and added a reference to a wcf service. `A` had a app.config file as part of the project. Hence the configurations will be generated over there automatically by VS. So when I build `A` I get `A`'s assemblies generated (`A.dll`, and `A.dll.config`) inside `A`'s bin folder

I add another project (`B`) into the solution. Add `A` project as reference. Hence on build of `B`, `A.dll` will get copied to `B`'s bin folder. I also modify my build properties such that `A.dll.config` gets copied post `B`'s build into B's bin directory.

In a method in a class, inside of `A.dll` I would have created my wcf proxy like:

```
var wcfProx = new MyWCFSvcClient();
```

This constructor's call actually picks values from the executing assembly's configuration file. If I wanted my wcf proxy to work I know I have to copy the system.ServiceModel in A's app.config to B's configuration file. This was what I had been doing erstwhile.

But now, what to do with the `Configuration` object I've opened via `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfig()`, and, how to associate that object to my wcf proxy instance? Meaning the proxy instance should derive values from `A.dll.config`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration() is what you're looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134269.aspx

In the sample code, the author copies the current configuration into a new file, then programmatically appends a new config section to the file.

After saving the changes and resetting the section, they are able to read the settings back out.

I was unable to determine if this alters the configuration of the current running application, but it's worth a shot.